# Applying Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be some category and let $G$ be a functor $\mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathcal{C}$. Assume that I was able to show that there is a natural isomorphism $\mathcal{C}(-, G(A \oplus B)) \Rightarrow \mathcal{C}(-, G(A) \times G(B)): \mathcal{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$, where $A$ and $B$ are two objects of $\mathcal{C}$, $\times$ is a Cartesian product in $\mathcal{C}$ and $\oplus$ a coproduct in $\mathcal{C}$.

By the Yoneda Lemma, I can deduce that $G(A \oplus B) \simeq G(A) \times G(B)$. Thus $G(A \oplus B)$ is a Cartesian product of $G(A)$ and $G(B)$ in $\mathcal{C}$. What are the projections? There are some natural candidates: $G((\iota^1)^{op})$ and $G((\iota^2)^{op})$, where $\iota^1: A \to A \oplus B$ and $\iota^2: B \to A \oplus B$ are the coprojections in $\mathcal{C}$.

How to check that it is indeed the case? Can I use the Yoneda Lemma for that?

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are objects in a category for which $X_1 \times X_2$ exists, consider the projections $\pi_i : X_1 \times X_2 \to X_i$. Then, if $P \cong X_1 \times X_2$ and $f : P \to X_1 \times X_2$ is a isomorphism, $\pi_i f : P \to X_i$ are the projections.

Comment: @azif00 Indeed, and thus the question is: do I need to make $f$ explicit and to compute $\pi_i \circ f$ and to compare it with $G((\iota^i)^{op})$ or can I avoid such computations to conclude with an abstract argument that anyway we have $\pi^i \circ f = G((\iota^i)^{op})$? Could it be the case that in this situation we have $\pi^i \circ f \not= G((\iota^i)^{op})$?

Answer (score 1):

No, your method does not work to compute the projections.

For consider $\mathcal{C} = Sets$ and $G = \Delta\mathbb{N}$ - that is, $G(A) = \mathbb{N}$, $G(f) = 1_\mathbb{N}$ for all $A, B \in \mathcal{C}$, $f : C(A, B)$.

Then there is a bijection $\tau : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ - that is, an isomorphism in the category of sets. This bijection lifts to a natural isomorphism $Sets(-, G(A \oplus B)) = Sets(-, \mathbb{N}) \to Sets(-, \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) = Sets(-, G(A) \times G(B))$.

But clearly, the maps $G(i_A) = 1_\mathbb{N} = G(i_B)$ are not the projection maps of the product.